# How do I figure out which channels my bot is in?

Tags: bots, slack, botframework

Using MS Bot Framework, how do I figure out which channels my bot is in, on slack?

Is it possible, without doing something slack specific?

I have tried doing something with the message type `BotAddedToConversation` but without any luck.

Basically, I would like to write to a channel, without having a message to reply to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Message** object that you get in the Post function of your Api, the **ChannelConversationId** property contains the Channel.

```
public async Task<Message> Post([FromBody]Message message)
{
    if (message.Type == "Message")
    {
        var channel = message.ChannelConversationId;
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that is correct. But what if I don't get messages, in the channels? I'm thinking there is no way to figure this out, except for storing channel-id's, from the various messages.

Comment: Nop, you have to get a message, otherwise you don't have a conversation :)